# How to connect ms access database from network drive

Tags: c#, ms-access-2010

I have tried to connect to `MS access database` on a network drive from `windows application.`

My connection string is:

```
Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=\\dtinaurdsna02\\LE-IN
\\Data_Analysis\\Quality_Rating_Tool.accdb
```

It's working on my system but it is throwing error on other systems (they have access to this network drive).

Comment: you need to pass some user name and password.

Comment: but it is shared drive & when I connect database it is connected successfully (without password)

Comment: You may have permissions (share and windows permissions) to access the files on that drive. The other users may not have the same windows permissions.

Comment: No All Users have permissions for that drive.we use that drive in other work

Comment: It is given below error  "When JIT debugging is enabled, any unhandled exception
will be sent to the JIT debugger registered on the computer
rather than be handled by this dialog box."

Comment: Make sure that Access is set to open in shared mode on all of the users' computers
https://support.office.com/en-in/article/Ways-to-share-an-Access-database-2c24eb08-bee1-453e-be8e-455f847c5c74#bm3

Comment: What is the error message?

Answer (score 1):

Microsoft Access database is designed to optimally work for one user at a time.  You can get around some of these limitations by linking the database.

Excerpt from [Access Database Best Practices](http://www.opengatesw.net/ms-access-tutorials/Access-Articles/MSAccess-Deployment-Best-Practices.htm)

> **Avoid Multi-User Collisions:** If you store all your objects in one file,
>   including your tables, Access will usually have difficulty when
>   multiple users attempt to open the same database file.  While Access
>   does have record-level locking, you may still receive errors that
>   another user is currently in the database and you cannot make changes.
>   To avoid this, you provide each end user with their own front-end
>   database file, each linked to the same Access Data File.

[image: multi user diagram]